# Repeated Values in Pivot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.
One with clients `debt`, the other with client `payments` with `dates`.

I want to create a new data frame with the % of the debt paid in the month of the payment until `01-2017`.

The problem is that some clients paid two times in the same month so there are repeated values and the pivot cant run that way and it shows :
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you for your time!

```
import pandas as pd 

d1 = {'client number': ['2', '2','3','6','7','7','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8'],
     'month': [1, 2, 3,1,10,12,3,5,8,1,1,4,5,8],
    'year':[2013,2013,2013,2019,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2014,2014,2015,2016,2017],
    'payment' :[100,100,200,10000,200,100,300,500,200,100,200,200,500,50]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1).set_index('client number')

d2 = {'client number': ['2','3','6','7','8'],
     'debt': [200, 600,10000,300,3000]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)


df2 = df2.set_index('client number')

df1['pct'] = df1['payment'].div(df1.index.map(df2['debt'])).round(2)
df1['date'] = df1['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df1['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df3 = df2.join(df1.pivot(columns='date', values='pct').fillna(0)).reset_index()
```

Comment: How would you want to handle duplicate values? Average them, add them? Also an expected output would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `agg_func='sum'`, as the fractions of monthly payments of debt can be added together:

```
df3 = (
    df2.join(
        df1.pivot_table(index=df1.index, columns='date', values='pct', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0))
    .reset_index()
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df3)

  client number   debt  2013-01  2013-02  2013-03  2013-05  2013-08  2013-10  2013-12  2014-01  2015-04  2016-05  2017-08  2019-01
0             2    200      0.5      0.5     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0
1             3    600      0.0      0.0     0.33     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0
2             6  10000      0.0      0.0     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0     0.00     0.00     0.00      1.0
3             7    300      0.0      0.0     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.67     0.33      0.0     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0
4             8   3000      0.0      0.0     0.10     0.17     0.07     0.00     0.00      0.1     0.07     0.17     0.02      0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot_table` instead. This allows you to apply a function to aggregate duplicate entries. For instance, you can take the max of duplicate values. Also, seems like you should include the `index` parameter in this function call. Replace your original `pivot` call with this:

```
df1.pivot_table(columns='date', index='client number', values='pct', aggfunc='max').fillna(0)
```